# How to calculate multiple cells and get parts of the formula to ignore "#DIV/0" as a value

Tags: excel, formula, equation

I am struggling to find an answer for this because other examples I have seen they are summing together a range in the examples given, the code I have here is this:

```
=(((H8/F8)*K8)+((N8/F8)*Q8)+((T8/F8)*W8)+((Z8/F8)*AC8)+((AF8/F8)*AI8))
```

Just an overview, the equation above is meant to work out a percentage and add it with the next percentage in the formula.

This works if all the cells I'm calculating contain numbers because its just a basic calculation but each section in this equation e.g. `((h8/f8)*k8)` - could equal `"#DIV/0!"` (because in some cases, there is no percentage value that needs to be calculated here), I know why it is doing this, but I am just wondering, is there a way to make each part of the equation ignore the `#DIV/0` if there is one present?

Comment: My only suggestion would be to put another formula in 1 more cell: let's assume the one you have is in cell BB8. So in cell BC8, put: `=if(iserror(BB8),"",BB8)`  or such ;)  Then you can "hide" cell BB8, and just show BC8. The error will be there, but not visible. Otherwise, you need to break out the smaller pieces of the larger formula in a similar way and check each piece if you wanted that ;)

Comment: In your example it looks like you are always dividing by the same cell, F8. Could you just wrap the whole formula in an IF that checks that F8 contains a number?

Comment: Thanks you your reply @Ditto, I was hoping to avoid creating another column by just doing it all with 1 single formula, I looked at the =sumif() statement in excel but that requires a range of data "=sumif(b2:b7,"<> #DIV/0!") - This works for a range but not for calculation.

Comment: That's quite exciting @Don't Panic, I will give that a go although thinking about it, I may need multiple if statements here because its not the f8 cell that is the worry here, its the other cells that are causing the hassle.

Comment: I only assumed this because in the example you provided, F8 is the only divisor, hence the only cell that could be responsible for #DIV/0.

Comment: This is now SOLVED, please see below :) thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the idea given from an above (@Gary's Student) answer I have solved this now, the formula I used was this:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((H8/F8)*K8,0)+IFERROR((N8/F8)*Q8,0)+IFERROR((T8/F8)*W8,0)+
     IFERROR((Z8/F8)*AC8,0)+IFERROR((AF8/F8)*AI8,0))
```

This has given me the exact answer that I wanted although it is a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
=(((H8/F8)*K8)+((N8/F8)*Q8)+((T8/F8)*W8)+((Z8/F8)*AC8)+((AF8/F8)*AI8))
```

with:

```
=IFERROR((((H8/F8)*K8)+((N8/F8)*Q8)+((T8/F8)*W8)+((Z8/F8)*AC8)+((AF8/F8)*AI8)),"")
```

Comment: This will not work because if this part, for example: ((AF8/F8)*AI8)) equals "#DIV/0!", I still want it to calculate the rest of the formula and provide the result.

Comment: @tombannister ...........Sadly Tom, if **F8** is **0**, then **all** terms in your formula will generate the error message.............. *Update your post to indicate the substitute formula that should be calculated if F8 is 0*

Comment: I have sorted this with your idea, the equastion I used I have posted as an answer, here is what I used: =SUM(IFERROR((H8/F8)*K8,0)+IFERROR((N8/F8)*Q8,0)+IFERROR((T8/F8)*W8,0)+IFERROR((Z8/F8)*AC8,0)+IFERROR((AF8/F8)*AI8,0))

Comment: The above checks each section for an error, if there is an error it puts the value to zero AND, it sums everything together so if one section of the equation equals "#DIV/0!" it will count it as zero so thanks :)